# Threaded messaging system for PHP/CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, messaging

Is there an open source threaded messaging library for CodeIgniter?  Or is it best to create the system in house?

I'm looking for a private messaging system with the basic person to person interactions, reply, attach etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I am aware of. Perhaps you could find a 'private messaging systems' in [PHP itself](http://pmsys.sourceforge.net/), and maybe port it over to CodeIgniter.

Alternatively, if you want one for your specific needs then yes, you should create it in house.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at a library I created that's been pretty popular:

http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/02/mahana-messaging-library

Has threaded messages, statuses set per user, multilingual error handling, transactions & a feature to allow users to be added to an existing thread and "catch up" on the full message stream

Comment: Mahana Messaging Library doesn't have receiver. Only sender is stored.
Anyone here modified it to use as private messaging system (so that receiver is also stored, functions to get receivers messages etc...)?

Comment: that's not true - why do you think that?

Comment: You are right @jmadsen. I read this text in the site "The messages table links to a thread, and include message body, priority, and who origininated the message (sender). Note that it does NOT include recipients; that is for the participants." and misunderstood that.

Answer (score 0):

Found one!

> CodeIgniter library to assist with hierarchal data such as threaded comments, drop down menus, and nested product categories

https://github.com/vmichnowicz/hierarchy